# How do I work with $scope and $watch with angular-fullstack generator syntax?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mean-stack, meanjs, angular-fullstack

I am using the [angular-fullstack generator](https://github.com/angular-fullstack/generator-angular-fullstack#route) to generate new routes for my application.  The syntax is [really unfamiliar](https://github.com/angular-fullstack/generator-angular-fullstack/blob/master/app/templates/client/app/main/main.controller.js) and uses a class-like structure.  How do I work with this to inject things like $scope and $watch?  The main thing I want to do is watch for a change for a particular variable.  The syntax is below.  Anybody know how to work with this?

```
'use strict';

(function() {

class MainController {

  constructor($http) {
    this.$http = $http;
    this.awesomeThings = [];

    $http.get('/api/things').then(response => {
      this.awesomeThings = response.data;
    });
  }

  addThing() {
    if (this.newThing) {
      this.$http.post('/api/things', { name: this.newThing });
      this.newThing = '';
    }
  }

  deleteThing(thing) {
    this.$http.delete('/api/things/' + thing._id);
  }
}

angular.module('myapp')
  .controller('MainController', MainController);

})();
```

How do I inject $watch so that I can do something like:

```
this.$watch('awasomeThings', function () { ... });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are intending (my assumption) for you to use Angular's `controllerAs` syntax. When you do that, you end up using `$scope` a lot less (if at all).

The reason is that your views no longer bind directly to the scope, they bind to properties of the controller. So in your `MyController` example above, the views can access the array of `awesomeThings` using a name for the controller that you supply:

```
<body ng-controller="MyController as myCtl">
  <p ng-repeat="thing in myCtl.awesomeThings">{{thing}}</p>
</body>
```

One case where you still need to use the `$scope` is when you want to use `$scope.$watch()`. In this case, inject the `$scope` into your controller, the same way it's being done with `$http` above:

```
class MyController {

  constructor($scope) {
    // use the $scope.$watch here or keep a reference to it so you can
    // call $scope.$watch from a method
    this.$scope = $scope; 
  }

}
```

PS: This syntax is most likely ES6 but I could be wrong ... I use Typescript which looks very similar.

Comment: Perfect, thanks.  It makes much more sense now.  I think they are indeed using ES6 and [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) for compiling it to regular javacript.

Comment: If you are using ES6, then you can declare your DI (for safe minification) also by inserting `static $inject = ['$scope'];` just under the class definition and before the constructor function. If your ES6 transpiler supports that static definition.